# Attach screen on a running terminal

Tags: unix, terminal, gnu-screen, gnu

I have a long running process in a (virtual) terminal that unfortunately was not started in a (gnu) screen session.

Is there a way to migrate it in a screen session? (obviously, without stopping it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reptyr` should work, although there is no 100% reliable way.